# ordering based on the key, order. PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The arrays here are `var_dump`s of an array I have created. I can post the logic for how the array is created should it be requested but I hope there is enough info to come up with an appropriate answer.

I have an interesting array, with an interesting sorting question. There is the `key=>value` aspect, where the value is an int. and then there is the key of `order` where its value is an int.

For example:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'main-page/_child_page' => 
        array (size=2)
          'order' => int 0
          'fields' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'main-page/_secondary_child_page' => int 1
```

The above var dump of an array contains two things: key of `order` with a value of `0` and a `key=>value` (element 2 in the array) with the value being `1`.

Right now this array is in perfect order. But what if `order` was 3? Well the way I would like the array to be sorted is that:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'main-page/_secondary_child_page' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'main-page/_child_page' => 
        array (size=2)
          'order' => int 3
          'fields' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
```

This is where I question - **can this be done?** and if so: How?

The concept of "order" or in this case: `order` and `key => order` are extremely important. I know that a new array would have to be made. But the question is how do I do this cleanly?

Comment: read it twice, no idea what you are asking

Comment: @Dagon You're on the other half of the earth, you have to rotate your monitor by 180° to read it :) Then it makes even less sense.

Comment: I have never seen `var_dump` output that looks like that. What version of PHP is this?

Comment: You need to use a custom sort function. the easiest way is to loop through your array, pull out an order val, then use `array_multisort` to sort the original array against the ordering array.

Comment: try here http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: TBH it might be easier if you said why you needed that and people could come up with a better solution than this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help:

```
usort($array,'compare');

function compare($item1,$item2){
   return getValue($item1) - getValue($item2);
}

function getValue($item){
    if(is_int($item))return $item;
    if(is_array($item))return getValue(reset($item));
    trigger_error(E_NOTICE,"undefined item type: ".$item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the purpose and possibilities of your array makes it difficult to give a good answer, but expanding on my comment above, the best way to do this is to create a secondary array of original keys to an order integer, then sort the original array based on that

*Note: i would recommend against using usort or any other such `A vs B` style sorters on the original array as the value retrieval will occur many times and thats an expensive process in your case ( see how `30` is passed in several times here https://ideone.com/OytXZd )*

Here's a function that does EXACTLY what you want so you should be able to work it out yourself from this.

```
function sortit(&$arr) {

   // creat ordering array
   $orderarr = array();
   foreach($arr as $k => $item) {

        // Default order is by key (fallback)
        $orderval = $k;

        if(is_array($item)) {

            // Get the first item
            $itemx = current($item);

            if(is_numeric($itemx)) {

                // If its a number, thats our value! 
                $orderval = $itemx;

            } else if (is_array($itemx) && isset($itemx['order'])) {

                // Only other thing we accept is an array containing the order key
                $orderval = intval($itemx['order']);

            }

        }

        // Build the ordering array
        $orderarr[$k] = $orderval;

   }

   // Sort the original array
   array_multisort($orderarr, SORT_ASC, $arr);      

}
```

See it here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/BfbvfH